# Log file data extraction

Tags: python

I have a log.txt file like this

```
2022-10-12 18:15:22.992 0026/? I/AsrDecActor25: channels=1, size=82434
2022-10-12 18:15:22.992 0026/? I/AsrDecActor25: waiting asr-core ready: 12 secs
2022-10-12 18:15:23.058 0199/? I/AsrDecActor27: asr state: START, true
2022-10-12 18:15:23.058 0199/? I/AsrDecActor27: asr state 2: START
2022-10-12 18:15:23.058 0199/? I/AsrDecActor27: end of decoding 57 true 0
NEC Input :secure folder app close it
NEC Replacement suggestion :Secure folder
NEC Input Before Replace : secure folder app close it
NEC Matching Word : secure folder app
Replaced Word  : Secure folder
NEC Output After Replace : Secure folder close it
Changes : 1
2022-10-12 18:15:23.060 0199/? I/LangPackActor: eASR [NEC] Run completed, Time: 2 ms
PostProcessSubstitutions::Output of question mark processing: secure folder uninstall Kare
[eITN] Input:Secure folder uninstall kare OutputSecure folder uninstall Kare
2022-10-12 18:15:23.069 0199/? I/LangPackActor: eASR [Timestamp] getTimestamp starts
2022-10-12 18:15:23.069 0199/? I/LangPackActor: eASR string2IntegerList 14 20 23 32 36 
2022-10-12 18:15:23.069 0199/? I/LangPackActor: eASR string2IntegerList 14 20 23 32 36 
2022-10-12 18:15:23.069 0199/? I/LangPackActor: eASR levenshteinMapping
2022-10-12 18:15:23.069 0199/? I/LangPackActor: eASR new ASRResult
2022-10-12 18:15:23.091 0021/? I/AsrDecActor26: decoding
```

Now I have written a code to extract the lines with beginning "NEC Input Before Replace", "NEC Matching Word", "Replaced Word" and "NEC Output After Replace" such that my output.txt file looks like this

```
NEC Input Before Replace : secure folder app close it
NEC Matching Word : secure folder app
Replaced Word  : Secure folder
NEC Output After Replace : Secure folder close it
```

I have written a code for the same

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
f = open('log.txt','r',encoding='utf-8')
f1 = open('output.txt', "w", encoding='utf-8')
#f1 = open('output.txt', 'a')

#doIHaveToCopyTheLine=False

for line in f.readlines():
    if 'NEC Input Before Replace' or 'NEC Matching Word' or 'Replaced Word' or 'NEC Output After Replace' in line:
        f1.write(line)

f1.close()
f.close()
```

But this code is giving the same output as the input

```
2022-10-12 18:15:22.992 0026/? I/AsrDecActor25: channels=1, size=82434
2022-10-12 18:15:22.992 0026/? I/AsrDecActor25: waiting asr-core ready: 12 secs
2022-10-12 18:15:23.058 0199/? I/AsrDecActor27: asr state: START, true
2022-10-12 18:15:23.058 0199/? I/AsrDecActor27: asr state 2: START
2022-10-12 18:15:23.058 0199/? I/AsrDecActor27: end of decoding 57 true 0
NEC Input :secure folder app close it
NEC Replacement suggestion :Secure folder
NEC Input Before Replace : secure folder app close it
NEC Matching Word : secure folder app
Replaced Word  : Secure folder
NEC Output After Replace : Secure folder close it
Changes : 1
2022-10-12 18:15:23.060 0199/? I/LangPackActor: eASR [NEC] Run completed, Time: 2 ms
PostProcessSubstitutions::Output of question mark processing: secure folder uninstall Kare
[eITN] Input:Secure folder uninstall kare OutputSecure folder uninstall Kare
2022-10-12 18:15:23.069 0199/? I/LangPackActor: eASR [Timestamp] getTimestamp starts
2022-10-12 18:15:23.069 0199/? I/LangPackActor: eASR string2IntegerList 14 20 23 32 36 
2022-10-12 18:15:23.069 0199/? I/LangPackActor: eASR string2IntegerList 14 20 23 32 36 
2022-10-12 18:15:23.069 0199/? I/LangPackActor: eASR levenshteinMapping
2022-10-12 18:15:23.069 0199/? I/LangPackActor: eASR new ASRResult
2022-10-12 18:15:23.091 0021/? I/AsrDecActor26: decoding
```

I am not getting what is going wrong. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `if` condition from

```
if (
    "NEC Input Before Replace"
    or "NEC Matching Word"
    or "Replaced Word"
    or "NEC Output After Replace" in line
):
    pass
```

to this

```
if (
    "NEC Input Before Replace" in line
    or "NEC Matching Word" in line
    or "Replaced Word" in line
    or "NEC Output After Replace" in line
):
    pass
```

This is because your current code will evaluate like this,

```
if (
    ("NEC Input Before Replace")
    or ("NEC Matching Word")
    or ("Replaced Word")
    or ("NEC Output After Replace" in line)
):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `'NEC Input Before Replace' or false` evaluates always to `true`.

You're check will have to look like this:

```py
for line in f.readlines():
    if 'NEC Input Before Replace' in line or \
         'NEC Matching Word' in line or \
         'Replaced Word' in line or \
         'NEC Output After Replace' in line:
        f1.write(line)
```